# Creating a Package with a Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a procedure where the input is lname from table Employee and output is sal and average from table Information. Both outputs are numbers and average is a decimal number. This is what I have so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE getSalAvgPack IS PROCEDURE getSalAvg
(name IN Employee.lname%TYPE,
 pSal OUT NUMBER,
 pAvg OUT NUMBER);
END;
.
/
```

The package compiles fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY getSalAvgPack IS PROCEDURE getSalAvg
(name IN Employee.lname%TYPE,
 pSal OUT NUMBER,
 pAvg OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT Information.sal, Information.average
  INTO pSal, pAvg
  FROM Information
  WHERE Information.eid=Employee.eid AND name=lname;
END;
END;
.
/
```

When I try to compile the package body I get these errors

```
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored (for line 7, column 2)
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "LNAME": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Do people these days really not get taught how to look at their own code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join in the `Employee` table:

```
  SELECT Information.sal, Information.average
  INTO pSal, pAvg
  FROM Information join
       Employee
       on Information.eid=Employee.eid
  WHERE name=lname;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are missing a join

```
SELECT Information.sal, Information.average
  INTO pSal, pAvg
  FROM Information
       JOIN Employee ON (Information.eid = Employee.eid)
 WHERE name = Employee.lname;
```

As a general principle, I would strongly suggest using a naming convention for your parameters that differentiates them from columns in your tables.  If `name` is a column in either table that you're joining, your predicate will compare the `Employee.lname` against that column rather than using the `name` parameter from your procedure.  A common convention is to prefix all parameters with `p_` so that your query becomes

```
SELECT Information.sal, Information.average
  INTO p_Sal, p_Avg
  FROM Information
       JOIN Employee ON (Information.eid = Employee.eid)
 WHERE p_name = Employee.lname;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I give a default value if sal or average is null? Simply saying 
    SELECT NVL(Information.sal, 'NA'), NVL(Information.average, 'NA') 

Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user2616744 - First, define "doesn't work." Second, what are the data types? I would guess that both `sal` and `average` are numeric columns. If so, it does not make sense for the `NVL` to try to return a string if the values are `NULL` since you can't convert the string `NA` to a number. If both columns are numeric types, the `NVL` would need to return a default numeric values. Of course, you could also define the procedure to return two strings and convert the numeric data to a string before returning it but that generally isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yeah you're right they are both NUMBER, so it should be 0 not NA. I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks!